# Как сделать проверку, чтобы допустимо было вводить только слитные цифры

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Чтобы  проверялись пробелы, символы, латиница, кирилица.
На несколько переменных

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $g33,$g44)
```

Как?

Comment: Пример приведите, что Вы хотите получить. Т.е. с чем сравнивать, что должно получиться на выходе...

Comment: Если пустое значение не должно вызывать ошибку, то можно просто объединить их через точку:  

    preg_match($re, $val1.$val2.$val3)
Допустимы ли пустые значения?

Comment: правильный обрабатываемый  это цифры от 1 до 40.
если ввели 2 2,уйцуйцб,eqweeqwe3123,41,44:40, 2 s 2
то к дальнешей обработке значение не идет
а если ввели от 1 до 40 то дальнейшие действия выполняются

Comment: так ?

    is_numeric($g33) &&(int)$g33==$g33 && $g33<40 && $g33>1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачи такого плана лучше не решать регексами, можно конечно это сделать, но это будет быдлокодие. Вам нужно нечто вроде:

```
$arr= Array($val1, $val2, $val3, ...);
echo checkValues($arr);
function checkValues($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v)
        if ($v<1 || $v>40) return False;
    return True;
};
```

Comment: Ого :-) как же я был глуп 4 года назад :-) несомненно, что задачу надо решать регулярными выражениями :-)

Answer (score 0):

Отличная программа для создания регулярок:

http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Не хотите разбираться в регулярках используйте, хотите - rtfm.

Answer (score 0):

Вот сервис для визуальной проверки регулярных выражений. При вводе регулярки рисует схему как она работает. Может поможет разобраться с самой регуляркой.

---

[ссылка](http://phpdes.com/online-services/onlajjn-servis-regulyarnyh-vyrazhenijj-regexper/)

Comment: ТС хочет передать в preg_match несколько переменных, которые должны быть проверены одним регулярным выражением. Конструкторы не помогут.

Comment: @ReinRaus, это, видимо, был автоответчик к вопросу с тегом «регулярные-выражения» :)

Comment: да нет. Я, например, при написании регулярки, проверяю ее на этом сервисе. Я не автоответчик)))